# Angular set ngStyle margin based on another html element's position

Tags: angular, view, lifecycle

In the view I have a table labeled as view variable, like so:

```
<table #mainTable class="country-fiches-table" cellspacing="0" border="1">
```

The mainTableX component variable in that same component is formed like so:

```
this.mainTableX = this.mainTable ? this.mainTable.nativeElement.offsetLeft : 0;
```

I want this `mainTableX` to be used as margin of another html element, like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'margin-left': mainTableX ? mainTableX : '0' }">another element</div>
```

I know the most useful advice to do here is to point me to the angular lifecycle, but it doesn't really show how precisely information about position of ALREADY RENDERED ELEMENT can be used on another element.

Any advice on this? If I put it in a method of the lifecycle that is sooner than the render time (specifically `ngAfterContentInit`), then the mainTableX is not formed, thus producing `0` as margin. If I, however, put it in a lifecycle method that is triggered after the rendering (specifically `ngAfterViewChecked`), then I get the error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

Comment: To avoid the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, you have to calculate `mainTableX` using the underlying model, NOT using the properties of the rendered HTML element. You could also look for an appropriate way to get the same result with CSS.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Do you however, really think that it is not possible, to take a position of a rendered html element and use it for another element, in angular?

Comment: I think it is possible if the property has not changed in the same change detection cycle.

Comment: Just wondering: maybe CSS could be used to achieve the same result (instead of calculating a left margin)?

Comment: Yeah, it can be done, I mean, I just thought of that :) but, I wanted to use already centered table, to position another div aligned with its left edge. Instead I can repack the whole thing in some manner, using plain html and css.

Comment: Done using only css and html repack, restructuring the elements on the page, adding some helping divs to wrap some elements etc. I did however wanted to do it via angular only.

Comment: will you posted it as answer, so that it will help someone.. :)

Comment: If you know which calculation/property affects the `offsetLeft` of `mainTable`, there should be a way to avoid the exception. In the end, it would probably be less efficient than CSS, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide your logic under set-timeout. This will resolve your issue.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.mainTableX = this.mainTable ? this.mainTable.nativeElement.offsetLeft : 0;
  },200);
}
```